# Converting Polar Equation to Cartesian Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

### Heading ##Convert polar equation to Cartesian equation.

$$r= \frac{2}{1-\cos\theta}$$

I tried to answer this and this is how I answered it. Please review if it's correct or not. Thank you! :)

\begin{align*}
r\cos\theta & = x\\
r\sin\theta & = y\\
r & = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
\end{align*}

I multiplied both sides by $1- \cos\theta$. 
$$r(1-\cos\theta) = \frac{2}{1-\cos\theta} \cdot (1-\cos\theta)$$

Then, it will become 
\begin{align*}
r(1-\cos\theta) & = 2\\
r - r\cos\theta & = 2\\
r - x & = 2\\
r & = x + 2\\
\sqrt{x^2+y^2} & = x+2
\end{align*}

Then, I multiplied both sides with 2 to eliminate the root.
\begin{align*}
2\sqrt{x^2+y^2} & = 2(x+2)\\
x^2+y^2 & = (x+2)^2\\
x^2+y^2 & = x^2+4x+4
\end{align*}

Combine like terms. 
\begin{align*}
x^2-x^2+y^2-4x+4 & = 0\\ 
y^2- 4x - 4 & = 0\\
y^2 & = 4x+4
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

$$r-r\cos\theta=2\iff r=r\cos\theta+2$$

$$x+2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

and $$x^2+y^2=(x+2)^2\iff4x+4=y^2$$

Comment: I don't understand. :(

Comment: @Lulu, Please find the updated version

Comment: How can I find the updated version? I'm confused. Someone edited my post and it looks confusing now.

Comment: @Lulu, I don't think you need a better solution. If you do, pay attention in class.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I'm sorry. I think you misunderstood my post. My teacher did not discuss this yet. She gave this homework to work on and test how we're going to answer this. My problem here is the new characters in this website. It has lots of dollar signs.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal at least I have the courage to help myself understand the homework than doing nothing :P

Comment: Your teacher gave it to you to test your creative abilities in math. I wish my teacher also did! Newton and Leibniz didn't have a little hint on what are limits and how could they create things "tending" to some value. And you are just posting the question here on MSE. IMO, you should try it first yourself. And you are doing nothing virtually. What you did is writing the questions here on MSE, I don't think it requires courage.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I'm not here to pick a fight Mr. Perfect. i just want to understand that number, so that I can answer the 9 remaining problems, okay? So, before you start pointing something, be helpful first okay? :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: This may help you understand the working here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29375/discussion-between-lulu-and-aditya-agarwal).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

From the diagram, you should be able to deduce the following relationships.
$$\tan\theta = \frac{y}{x}$$
$$x = r\cos\theta$$
$$y = r\sin\theta$$
$$r^2=x^2+y^2$$
Now, try to solve the problem using stategic substitutions.

Comment: Thank you for the great help..